# Cakephp How to Make Request data contain only the selected field values

Tags: ajax, cakephp, request, field

Iam Using Cakephp 2.4.6 version. Currently I am facing a problem with some fields in the forms. I have a group of horizontal controls in which  the first control is a checkbox which hold the id value.if id is selected then only i want to get all other controls in that row.
is there any way other than getting all values into ajax and send thorough ajax.

```
    TFmPlanProgram' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        't_fm_program_id' => '42',
        'number_of_time' => '10'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        't_fm_program_id' => '43',
        'number_of_time' => '10'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        't_fm_program_id' => '44',
        'number_of_time' => '15'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        't_fm_program_id' => '0',
        'number_of_time' => ''
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        't_fm_program_id' => '0',
        'number_of_time' => ''
    ),
```

This is my array. in that  you can  see that 3 and 4 having no id value. but it is passed to the server. i want to pass only the selected ID's.

Comment: Why not just take those that don't have `id` zero?

Comment: can you give us your view script atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this before calling $this->TFmPlanProgram->save();

```
        foreach($this->request->data['TFmPlanProgram'] as $key => $value){
            if(empty($value['number_of_time'])){
                unset($this->request->data['TFmPlanProgram'][$key]);
            }
        }
```